# axis2 support in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, apache-axis

I am using netbeans 7.0 and want to generate axis 2 web service from my java code.
I googled and it and found that they removed support for axis to in 7.0 v.

Then i came across this link
http://netbeans-org.1045718.n5.nabble.com/Axis2-Support-in-Netbeans-7-0-td4383308.html

Someone there mentioned to use plugin the Dynamic "Development UC" update center.
Now i have the updates.xml file.What should i do with it to install the plugin?

Answer (score 4):

In Netbeans, go to `Tools/Plugins/Settings`

`ADD`, enter a name, then pass in the url you've got.
That will load another bunch of plugins for Netbeans, then in the 'Available plugins', you should now have the 'Axis2 Support' plugin there ready to install.

When I installed it like this it wasn't enough, I also had to right click on it from the installed plugin list, and then click Activate.